# case or If string contains word1 and word2

Tags: bash, if-statement, case

In this example I want it to know if $@ contains two words/symbols "load" and "/"

for one word/symbol this works

```
    case "$@" in */*)
    ;;
    echo "going to do stuff"
*)
    echo "will do something else"
    ;;
esac
```

or

```
string='My string';

if [[ "$string" == *My* ]]
then
  echo "It's there!";
fi
```

But if two words/symbols appear at random places I cant figure out how to do it.

Update:

The input will the module command. In this case I want to know if it is the module load with or without / that indicate version. the command will look like this

1) module load appname/1.1.1 or
2) module load appname
3) module (not load) (list, avail etc)

It is number 1 I am interested in for now.
3 will in some cases be variation of 1.
2 will be run as is but will include a message to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is possible:

```
if  [[ ${@} =~ .*/.* && ${@} =~ ((^)|([ ]))load(($)|([ ])) ]]
then
  echo both
fi
```

-or-

```
if LOAD=0 && SLASH=0 && \
   for ARG in ${@};
   do
     if [ "${ARG#*/}" != "${ARG}" ]; then SLASH=1; fi
     if [ "${ARG}" = "load" ]; then LOAD=1; fi
   done && [ "${LOAD}${SLASH}" = "11" ];
then
  echo both
fi
```

-or-

```
function loadslash()
{
  LOAD=0 && SLASH=0
  for ARG in ${@};
  do
    if [ "${ARG#*/}" != "${ARG}" ]; then SLASH=1; fi
    if [ "${ARG}" = "load" ]; then LOAD=1; fi
  done
  test "${LOAD}${SLASH}" = "11"
}

if loadslash ${@}
then
  echo both
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The slow way would be to iterate through the array twice and then check if both "load" and "/" were present, like this:

```
for element in $@; do [[ "$element" == "load" ]] && loadPresent=1; done
for element in $@; do [[ "$element" =~ ".*/.*" ]] && slashPresent=1; done
if [[ $loadPresent == 1 ]] && [[ $slashPresent == 1 ]]; then
   echo "Contains load and /"
fi
```

(As I interpreted your question you want one parameter to be exactly "load" and another one to contain a slash.)

Comment: sure this is correct? se my result here in a test script: http://pastebin.com/XbN67n5d The loadPresent in the if statement seam to be empty.

Comment: Could you paste your "element"-script, too? If it looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/M2ZsS55g) it'll work [correctly](http://pastebin.com/rkKMk0Uq).

Answer (score 0):

this will satisfy your requirements

```
if [[ $1 == "load" ]]; then
    if [[ $2 == */* ]]; then
        do first case
    else
        do second case
    fi
else
    do third case
fi
```

Comment: This solution does not necessarily factor in the OP statement "But if two words/symbols appear at random places".  It only allows for the slash being at a random place inside $2.